# Button with multi-tasks in javascript

Tags: javascript

how I can get a multifunction button in JS? For example:
the first click will move the button down, the next click will return it to the default place.

```
let caoButton = document.querySelector('.js-cao-2');
caoButton.style.position = 'absolute';
caoButton.style.top = '0';
caoButton.style.left = '0';

caoButton.addEventListener('click',() {
caoButton.style.top = 'unset';
caoButton.style.left = 'unset';
caoButton.style.bottom = '0';
caoButton.style.right = '0';
});
```

Comment: Toggling a class on it would be the cleanest approach. Then use css rules

Comment: yes, with CSS rules it's ok, but how to make it with JS? Anyway, your answer helped me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agree with @charlietfl

```js
let caoButton = document.querySelector('.js-cao-2');

caoButton.addEventListener('click',()=>caoButton.classList.toggle("moveDown"));
```

```css
.js-cao-2{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.moveDown {
  top: unset;
  left: unset;
  bottom: 0; 
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 100vh">
  <button class="js-cao-2" >Move me</button>
</div>
```

In case you wish to do something more that just manipulate the css and you must use JavaScript, you can also do something like:

```
let caoButton = document.querySelector('.js-cao-2');

caoButton.addEventListener('click',firstFunctionality);

function firstFunctionality(){
  caoButton.removeEventListener('click', firstFunctionality)
  caoButton.addEventListener('click',secondFunctionality);
  //do stuff here
}

function secondFunctionality(){
  caoButton.removeEventListener('click', secondFunctionality)
  caoButton.addEventListener('click', firstFunctionality);
  //do something different here
}
```

Comment: I was needed in this solution! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This will trigger multiple actions on the button.

```js
let caoButton = document.querySelector('.js-cao-2');

const allTasks = (function* makeTaskGetter(){
  const tasks = [
  'js-cao-2-down', 
  'js-cao-2-right', 
  'js-cao-2-up',
  'js-cao-2-left'
  ];
  for (const task of tasks) { yield task; }
})();

caoButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const { value : task } = allTasks.next();
  caoButton.classList.add(task);
});
```

```css
.js-cao-2 {
  position: absolute;
}

.js-cao-2-down {
  top: 100px;
}

.js-cao-2-right {
  left: 100px;
}

.js-cao-2-up {
  top: 10px;
}

.js-cao-2-left {
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button class="js-cao-2">Click Me</button>
```

Also consider using `transform: translate` depending on your use case.